# using constexp member function in switch

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Why I can use constexp non-member function in switch, but when I use member function compiler is saying: "the value of ‘y’ is not usable in a constant expression"?

```
class Test {
public:
    constexpr Test(int i) : i(i) { }
    constexpr int get() {return i;};
private:
    int i;
};

constexpr int test()
{
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;

    Test y = Test(4);

    switch (x) {
    case test(): // this is OK
            break;
    case y.get(): // not working
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `y` as a constant expression:

```
constexpr Test y = Test(4);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/5QsT2A)

**Reason:**

Although, `Test::get()` is declared `constexpr` object `y` is not.

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

The problem with your code is that the Standard ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) mandates that each expression associated with a *label* must be a *constant-expression*.

> `6.4.2p2` **The *switch* statement** `[stmt.switch]`
>
> > Any statement within the switch statement can be labeled with one or more case labels as follows:
> >
> > case constant-expression :
> >
> > where the *constant-expression* shall be a converted constant expression (5.19) of the promoted type of the switch condition.

Since `y` is not declared in a *constant-expression* friendly matter, `y.get()` isn't usable when specifying the *needle* for a certain case-label. The *member-function* is *constexpr*, but the instance of `Test` isn't, which renders the usage of `Test::get` as a *non-constant expression*.

---

#### Solution

To solve this issue you will need to declare `y` with the `constexpr` specifier to enable its usage in the context you are looking for, and I'm guessing you already know how:

```
constexpr Test y (4);
```